# how to copy python apt installed .so module to non-default python interpreter

Tags: python, linux, apt

I have installed cv2 using `apt install python3-opencv` in my server. When I run some python file that uses cv2, I had the error `module not found`. After searching I realized that this happens because I use non default interpreter to run my python file (which I really need to use instead of the default interpreter).

If I typed `python3 myfile.py`, the error doesn't appear and the package is there. However, I want to use another interpreter `/some/path/here/python3.6` but when I use it the module is not found. I searched for cv2 location and I found it, which is this

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-opencv
/usr/share/doc/python3-opencv/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-opencv/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Now I want this package to be copied to the interpreter I always use, how can I do that? or how can I make apt install the package to my interpreter?

Thank you